# Swedish language Watson Conversation bot

Tags: watson-conversation, watson-assistant

I'd like to know what my options are for creating a Swedish language chatbot using Watson Conversation? To give some background, I am an English speaking developer and I have a requirement to develop a chatbot for a Swedish speaking client company. What occurred to me was to capture all the utterances in Swedish and link them to the relevant intents, that way I can make it bilingual if I want by capturing utterances in English too. Am I missing something here maybe?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use language translator.
Translate Swedish language input to English.
Built Chat bot in English.
Then Same way convert English responses in Swedish.

Comment: Is that a specific service on IBM Bluemix, or do you mean just some language translator service out there?

Comment: You don't need to convert English responses as WA supports unicode, so you can put Swedish responses in. But translating from one language to another has a lot of issues with it. (1) It is harder to get true representative questions, (2) translations can lose meaning both in words and concepts, which can impact training. You can mitigate some of this by picking a supported language that is closer to the language you are trying to do.